# Package excluded from apt full-upgrade yet notified that update is available

Tags: command-line, upgrade

I am not fully grasping this upgrade problem. Can someone please enlighten me?

```
$ apt list --upgradable

Listing... Done

modemmanager/hirsute-updates 1.16.6-2~21.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.14.10-0.1]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

$ apt list --upgradable -a

Listing... Done

modemmanager/hirsute-updates 1.16.6-2~21.04 amd64 [upgradable from: 
modemmanager/hirsute,now 1.14.10-0.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1.16.6-2~21.04]
```

When performing

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

that package does not get updated with full-upgrade. However, under `sudo apt update` it keeps notifying that an upgrade is available.

If `sudo apt full-upgrade` is suppose to upgrade all available packages, why is this not being included?

Comment: Is it a problem ? Can you do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` ?

Comment: Yes, I can sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade. My system itself seems fine. I am merely trying to understand why this modemanager update isn't fully installing, specifically so...

Comment: What problem do you mean?  There are cases where `apt upgrade` cannot upgrade all packages, and a `apt full-upgrade` is required... (usually when packages need to be removed; the `apt upgrade` itself will skip those packages) ... you can read the reference manual page with `man apt`

Comment: The command you issued only lists what is upgradeable.  It doesn't perform the actual upgrade.  So, there's nothing wrong.  If you do a `apt full-upgrade`, you'll get a message about issues related to the actual upgrade, if there are issues with the upgrade.  (i.e., conflicts, etc.)

Comment: The body of the question in no way matches the question asked. Please edit.

Comment: I think everyone's missing the point of my question. How do I upgrade the upgradable, when it's not allowing me to?

Comment: I had the same a couple of days ago, a few days later the package 'modemmanager` got upgraded during `apt full-upgrade`. Seems to be a small bug in the package but seems to be fixed already. It may depend on the update mirror you use when you get the fixed version.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's latest comment to the question.

Currently the package modemmanager can only be upgraded if you also manually install the correct dependencies. Version 1.16.6-2 appears to be a hotfix for specific modems (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/modemmanager/+bug/1934286).

In order for this package to install, you also need to install another dependency that seems to be not released yet as the main update candidate:

`libqmi-glib5 v.1.28.6-1`

If you do a `apt-cache policy libqmi-glib5` you'll see that it's available in the `-updates` source, but I would imagine that manually installing that may start a list of other dependencies that you may potentially need to upgrade as well.

To be fair, the modemmanager update appears to have been released today. So give it some time.

If you choose to install it regardless, the way to specify the specific version number is:
`sudo apt install modemmanager=1.16.6-2~21.04` where
`sudo apt install package_name=version_num`

Edit:
As of Sept 2 2021, `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` should resolve this issue as the candidate for `libqmi-glib5` and some others have been upgraded as well